# django data in form only appear after refresh

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using custom user authentication for verifying user. I have table named voter and I am tacking username and password via from and matching that with username and password of table if it match user will be logged in and allowed them to pass to next page which contain form. In that form I initiated data but it will not appear automatically it will appear only when i refresh the page

code of my files is bellow (for some big file only relevant code is included that's why it is partial)

model.py (partial)

```
    class Voter(models.Model):
        serial_voter_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        voter_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
        voter_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        voter_constituency = models.ForeignKey(Constituency, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)
        password = models.TextField()
        voter_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        area = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
        pincode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        adhar_no = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
        birth_date = models.DateField()
        age = models.IntegerField()
        fingerprint = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        authenticity = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
        wallet_id = models.TextField()

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'voter'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Voter

class VoterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Voter
        fields = [
            'serial_voter_id',
            'voter_id',
            'voter_name',
            'voter_constituency',
            'username',
            'voter_address',
            'area',
            'city',
            'pincode',
            'adhar_no',
            'birth_date',
            'age',
            'authenticity',
            'wallet_id'
        ]
```

views.py (partial)

```
from .models import Voter
from .forms import VoterForm

def voter_login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    contex = {}
    return render(request, "poll/voter_login.html", contex)


def voter_verification(request, *args, **kwargs):
    f_username = request.POST.get('username')
    voter = Voter.objects.get(voter_id=1) # thing need to be dynamic hear by replacing it with username
    f_username = request.POST.get('username')
    f_password = request.POST.get('password')
    u_password = voter.password # fetching the password from voter object
    u_password = u_password.decode() # decoding binary password to string
    form = VoterForm(request.POST or None, instance=voter)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = VoterForm()
    contex = {
        'voter' : voter,
        'f_username' : f_username,
        'f_password' : f_password,
        'u_password' : u_password,
        'form'       : form
    }
    # compare hear username and password entered by user and from database if these are correcgt then allow this view or redirect to voter_login view
    if voter.username == f_username and u_password == f_password:
        return render(request, "poll/voter_verification.html", contex)
    else:
        return render(request, "poll/voter_login.html", {})
```

voter_login.html

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}
<table>
<form method="get" action='voter_verification'> {% csrf_token %}
    username <input type="text" name="username">
    password <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

voter_verification.html (template file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

{% if f_username == voter.username and f_password == u_password %}
    <h1>verified</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>wrong id and password</h1>
{% endif %}

<form method='post' action='vote_page'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value="sumbit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DrMaxwellEdison from reddit for providing answer
https://www.reddit.com/r/djangolearning/comments/fecn1f/question_django_data_in_form_only_appear_after/

Please do not have a separate model that stores usernames and passwords aside from your User model. You can simply add a OneToOneField to the User model to connect this Voter model to the authenticated User, and you don't need to do any extra data storage (plus, you are more likely to be handling the password information incorrectly, exposing it to being compromised if your site is breached).

Also per your comment on SO, the POST is not working because of CSRF protection (the traceback of your error would likely have indicated this already). Please see those docs for details on how to proceed (hint: do not disable CSRF!).

Answer (score 0):

changes query in view model ( def voter_verification(request, *args, **kwargs):)

```
def voter_verification(request, *args, **kwargs):
    f_username = request.POST.get('username')
    voter = Voter.objects.get(username=f_username)
```

then request user check in voter table which have exits with same user name.

Comment: I know that get method can work. but as you can see I also need to pass password so I can't use get method. Do you have any idea why post method is not working ? @Gaurav Goyal

Comment: voter object access the password of as usual.                                              `u_password = voter.password`  # fetching the password from voter object

Comment: voter.password is the password from database. f_password is from previous page. In order to verify we need to compare f_password with that of database password. So we need both these variable.